# Scaffolding Error in ASP.Net MVC 3 when creating controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I try to add a new controller using scaffolding, I get this message

```
"Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Model name'. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key"
```

Can anyone help?
This is the Model use for scaffolding

```
public class Patient
    {
        [Key]
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public int FamilyPhone1 { get; set; }
        public int FamilyPhone2 { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Drug> Drugs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Alert> Alerts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Patient
{
    [Key]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; } ==> Replace String by string with a lower case
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public int FamilyPhone1 { get; set; }
    public int FamilyPhone2 { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Drug> Drugs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Alert> Alerts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```